# AsyncTask и зависание фрагмента (DrawerLayout)

Tags: java, android-fragment, android-asynctask, drawerlayout

В проекте использую для выезжающего меню `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`.

При клике на пункте меню, расположенного в нём, через `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` загружаю нужный `fragment`, в котором в свою очередь происходит загрузка контента через `AsyncTask`.

Но при этом же клике меню не скрывается до тех пор, пока не пройдет полная загрузка данных... сам `AsyncTask` запускаю в `onCreateView` фрагмента.
Получается, что фризится UI до момента загрузки, что плохо.

Необходимо, чтобы сразу скрывалось меню, загружался `layout` фрагмента, а уже потом дожидаться завершения `AsyncTask`. Почему `AsyncTask` запущенный во фрагменте фризит UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описанное вами в обычном исполнении такого поведения вызывать не должно. Судя по всему, проблема в вашем `AsyncTask`. Вы или в `onPreExecute` что-то не то делаете, либо (я ставлю на это) вы используете где-то в коде `get()` метод вашего `AsyncTask` коий, как раз, и способен лишить `AsyncTask` всех своих прелестей заморозкой UI-потока.

Comment: Да, верно, использую. Предлагаете обойтись без него? Пропадет фриз?

Comment: Да, уберите `get()` и зависание исчезнет. А результат выполнения `AsyncTask ` надо в `onPostExecute()` получать и обрабатывать.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за Ваш опыт!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)